# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono

Sometimes, when running a Mono .NET application (it seems to not depend on the input data, as it does not change), I run into following situation:
when trying to Dequeue an element from a (non-empty, I check its Count beforehand) Queue, an exception is thrown:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
>   at System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[DBWorkItem].Peek ()[0x00000]
>     at System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[DBWorkItem].Dequeue () [0x00000]
>     at DBProcessor.process (System.Object q) [0x0006b] in <...>

Though I can certainly catch this exception, the element is dequeued and lost. Has anyone else encountered this behavior, too?

Comment: Are you accessing this Queue from multiple threads?

Answer (score 5):

Do you have multiple threads using this queue? It may be non-empty when you check the count, but then empty when you try to peek the item.

If you have a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, we could tell for sure. Of course, it's possible that it's a Mono bug, although my experience is that system frameworks are usually more robust than the code calling into them.

Comment: I am indeed using several threads, however each thread has its own queue (containing work items to be fired against the database), so this should not be a problem. However, I'll try to investigate it.

Unfortunately, the code is much too complex to post it here...

Comment: @DBa: Then take the code and hammer it until it's *not* too complex to post here. You *say* that each thread has its own queue - how sure are you that that's really the case? That may be the intention, but if two threads are checking the same queue, that could be the problem.

Comment: @DBa, did you get a solution for this issue? Any update? Help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @JonSkeet I get the same exception. Code is in MVC5 application on Mono. Code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8feb761869d5d47ce140

Comment: Solution was to use a [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the [`TryDequeue(out T result)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287208%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Probably something to do with threading in Razor?